# jquery-ui menu keep sub menu open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu, jquery-ui-menubar

Assume I have this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pnmpn25/VPXjs/

```
$( "#menu" ).menu();
```

It's the demo implementation from the jquery ui site. 
When I click on Salzburg->Delphi the submenu for Delphi stays open, this is what I want.

When I click on Salzburg->Delphi->Delphi or 
Salzburg->Perch, the submenu closes. I dont want this.

How can I get the jquery ui menu to not close a submenu if the submenu doesnt have any child menus? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if i don't really understand why you want to do such action (it's quite a common thing to close the menu when item is selected), you can call `focus()` method when an item is selected to prevent menu from closing like in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPXjs/1/)

Comment: Cool, thank you, I want to keep the menu open because I have checkboxes within the menu, allowing multi selection, so I needed to have the sub menus stay open unless clicked in the document. Thanks again.